# More then one command in onclick function

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have radiobuttons in a form where I added onclick functions, so that the form gets submited as soon I click on a radiobutton.

```
<td>@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.SelectedTeacher, Model.ListofTeacher[i].ID, new { @onclick = "javascript: this.form.submit();"})</td>
```

That works fine but now I want to add a second command in the onclick function.

It should change the action "Example" in the form.

```
using (Html.BeginForm("Example", "Home", new { id = "form" })){}
```

So I tried this

```
<td>@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.SelectedTeacher, Model.ListofTeacher[i].ID, new { @onclick = "document.getElementById('form').action = 'Delete';
    this.form.submit();" })</td>
```

but this does not work.

Can someone explain to me how I do it properly?

I don't really have skills in js, so if I lack information please ask!

Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Using `onclick` you can only register one event with action.

If you want to register multiple events you need to use [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#Why_use_addEventListener.3F) and is the way to register an event listener as specified in W3C DOM.

```
var radios = document.getElementsByName('SelectedDevice');
for (i = 0; i < radios.length; i++) {
    radios[i].addEventListener('click', onRadioButtonClick);
    radios[i].addEventListener('click', onRadioButtonClick2);
}

function onRadioButtonClick() {
    document.getElementById('form').action = 'Delete';
    this.form.submit();
}
```

You can also use one event listener to perform all of operations instead of hooking multiple events.

In HTML:

```
<td>@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.SelectedDevice, Model.ListofDevice[i].ID, new { @onclick = "onRadioButtonClicked" })</td>
```

In JavaScript:

```
function onRadioButtonClick() {
    document.getElementById('form').action = 'Delete';
    this.form.submit();

    // Your other operations here
}
```

Comment: Add one event listener and put all of your actions in there.  Definitely do not add multiple event listeners for something like this.